# YVR (Vancouver) to DUB (Dublin) through MUC (Munich)

Tags: canada, layovers, hidden-city-ticketing

I bought a return YVR to DUB for around $860 with a layover in MUC. I will be travelling without luggage. 
I want to get off in MUC but still use the return from DUB.
YVR/DUB is operated by Lufthansa. DUB/YVR is operated by Air Canada.

If I don't board the connector MUC to DUB, will my return DUB to YVR be cancelled?

Comment: The answer to your question is generally "yes, as soon as you miss a flight, all remaining legs on that itinerary are cancelled."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your return flight will be cancelled, unless you contact the ticketing carrier and rebook the flight to be an open jaw, YVR-MUC and DUB-MUC-YVR.  This may change the fare, and will be subject to the rebooking terms of the fare class you purchased.

Had you booked these as two one-way flights, you would have been able to do what you propose without any harm, but that may have cost more than a return ticket did.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...first post.  I did mean Munich (MUC) and DUB is Dublin.  thanks for the responses, very helpful.